# C++ insert char into string

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string may = "I katf kpg";

may.insert(5, " ");
}
```

That's my code here's the problem: how do I insert a space in front and after the `t`, in the `may` string?

So it will be "I ka t f kpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> here's the prob How do I insert a space in front and after the t, in
>   the May string

Replace

`may.insert(5, ' ');`

with

`may.insert(5, " ");`

You need use double quotes for String, not single quotes which mean char.

**Update**

It seems that your requirement is to do the insert at two places at the same time. Try following:

`may.insert(4, " ").insert(6, " ");`

Comment: Well, you're wrong. _"You need use double quotes for String, not single quotes which mean char."_ No, there are overloads for `std::string::insert` that take `char`. And, indeed, those are what the OP _should_ be using here. That being said, your solution will also work.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, there are no overloads of `std::string::insert` which take just two arguments and the second argument is of type `char`.

Comment: But how do I put a space in front of the t and after AT THE SAME TIME

Comment: Sample code please for my case then I'll understand

Comment: @VHS: I did not claim that there were.

Comment: @Barry, well it does. But the first argument needs to be of type `iterator`.

Comment: Actually you want #1. Come on guys this is easy